# How to disable mopier mode in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, printer

My computer only prints one copy of anything I send it, even if I request more. After some searching, I figured it was a problem with mopier mode.

I tried to follow a Windows tutorial on how to disable it (because I didn't find anything about Linux), but I can't find any equivalent option.

Here is what I've got in my printer options:

[image: Printer options]

For non-French speaker, this roughtly translates to:

- Pages per side
- Recto-verso
- Orientation
- Media Size
- Paper source
- Paper type

The "Color" tab only contains "Print Color Mode" and the "Advanced" tab only contains "Print Quality".

Obviously, I don't have any mopier mode in those menus.

Is there another way (command line, maybe) to check if the mopier mode is activated and deactivate it if so?

**NOTE:** I just changed from Fedora 29 to Fedora 30 with a complete reinstall. I could print multiple copies before the change.

Comment: Does [When printing multiple copies or a multi-page document, only a single copy or page is printed - Windows](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/52775/~/when-printing-multiple-copies-or-a-multi-page-document%2C-only-a-single-copy-or) help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't have that option.